# Can't connect tp SQL Server in android studio via TCP/IP

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio

Im' trying to connect to SQL Server database, it worked before but i don't know what's wrong here, can someone help
Maybe it's worth mentioning that i'm using mobile hotspot to connect to internet with pc (it has worked previously)

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionClass() {
        Connection con = null;

        String ip = "192.168.132.47", port = "1433", username = "abderahman", password = "admin", databasename = "APM_Recherche_Emploi";
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy tp = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":" + port + ";databasename=" + databasename + ";User=" + username + ";password=" + password + ";";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e("Error", exception.getMessage());
        }

        return con;
    }
```

Click listener code

```
 sauvegarder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String strnomEntreprise = nomEntreprise.getText().toString();
                String strsecAct = secAct.getText().toString();
                String strlieuAct = lieuAct.getText().toString();
                String strdesc = descriptionEntreprise.getText().toString();

                Connection connection;
                ___ConnectionClass c = new ___ConnectionClass();
                connection = c.connectionClass();
                if (connection != null) {

                    try {

                       String SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO Recruteur (Nom, Prenom, Entreprise, Description_Entreprise, Lieu_Activite_Entreprise, Secteur_Activite, Num_Tel, Email, Mot_de_passe) VALUES('" + nomRec + "','" + prenomRec + "','" + strnomEntreprise + "','" + strdesc + "','" + strlieuAct + "','" + strsecAct + "','" + telRec + "','" + emailRec + "','" + passRec + "');";
                        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                        int resultSet = statement.executeUpdate(SQLinsert);


                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("Error", exception.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.pfe_jobz_recherche_emploi">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
       // just activities here 
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Added jtds jar file, and TCP/IP is enabled

Comment: `192.168.132.47` is a non-routable address for a LAN, you won't be able to reach it from a mobile (cellular) hotspot. Have you tried reconnecting to your LAN's wi-fi access point?